# how is Matrix Multiplication with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have a 2D matrix for example `X=np.ones((97,2))` and another vector for example `Theta=np.zeros((2,1))`
when I multiply the vector Theta and the Matrix X, it raises an error

```
'operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,1) (97,2)'
```

but when I multiply `Theta.T* x`, it output a new `(97, 2) matrix`.

How did it work? How `(1,2) *(97,2)` works and if the shapes don't matter why it raises an error when `Theta * X` could anyone explain it, please.

Comment: Matrix multiplication should be `X @ Theta`. `Theta.T * X` is **element-wise** multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tries to broadcast ( = replicate) the smaller array across the larger one when a matrix multiplication doesn't work by dimensions, which is why your second example works but the first one doesn't.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html